# How to put a Json-File with HTML information into the DOM?

Tags: javascript, facebook, jquery, firefox-addon

I'm writing a firefox-extension and I've got this little json file:

```
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":{"stackable":[true,false],"title":{"__html":"How You Connect"},"body":{"__html":"\u003cdiv class=\"pam\">\u003cul class=\"uiList\">\u003cli class=\"pbm uiListItem uiListLight uiListVerticalItemBorder\">\u003cdiv class=\"clearfix fbPrivacyConnectItem\">\u003cdiv class=\"privacyLabel lfloat\">Who can look up your profile by name or contact info?\u003c\/div>\u003cdiv class=\"itemControl rfloat\">\u003cdiv class=\"uiSelector inlineBlock audienceSelector dynamicIconSelector uiSelectorRight uiSelectorNormal uiSelectorDynamicLabel uiSelectorDynamicTooltip\" data-name=\"audience[8787330733][value]\">\u003cdiv class=\"wrap\">\u003ca class=\"uiTooltip uiSelectorButton uiButton\" onmouseout=\"this.blur();\" role=\"button\" href=\"#\" aria-haspopup=\"1\" data-length=\"30\" rel=\"toggle\">\u003ci class=\"mrs defaultIcon customimg img sp_7kwant sx_b2461a\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"uiButtonText\">Everyone\u003c\/span>\u003cspan class=\"uiTooltipWrap top right righttop\">\u003cspan class=\"uiTooltipText uiTooltipNoWrap\">Everyone\u003c\/span>\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003cdiv class=\"uiSelectorMenuWrapper uiToggleFlyout\">\u003cdiv role=\"menu\" class=\"uiMenu uiSelectorMenu\">\u003cul class=\"uiMenuInner\">\u003cli class=\"uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption fbPrivacyAudienceSelectorOption checked\" data-label=\"Everyone\">\u003ca class=\"itemAnchor itemWithIcon\" role=\"menuitemradio\" tabindex=\"0\" aria-checked=\"true\" href=\"#\" rel=\"async-post\" ajaxify=\"\/ajax\/privacy\/simple_save.php?id=8787330733&amp;audience_json=\u00257B\u0025228787330733\u002522\u00253A\u00257B\u002522value\u002522\u00253A\u00252280\u002522\u00257D\u00257D\">\u003ci class=\"mrs itemIcon img sp_7kwant sx_b2461a\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"itemLabel fsm\">Everyone\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003c\/li>\u003cli class=\"uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption fbPrivacyAudienceSelectorOption\" data-label=\"Friends of Friends\">\u003ca class=\"itemAnchor itemWithIcon\" role=\"menuitemradio\" tabindex=\"-1\" aria-checked=\"false\" href=\"#\" rel=\"async-post\" ajaxify=\"\/ajax\/privacy\/simple_save.php?id=8787330733&amp;audience_json=\u00257B\u0025228787330733\u002522\u00253A\u00257B\u002522value\u002522\u00253A\u00252250\u002522\u00257D\u00257D\">\u003ci class=\"mrs itemIcon img sp_8n1pd0 sx_20b2e8\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"itemLabel fsm\">Friends of Friends\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003c\/li>\u003cli class=\"uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption fbPrivacyAudienceSelectorOption\" data-label=\"Friends\">\u003ca class=\"itemAnchor itemWithIcon\" role=\"menuitemradio\" tabindex=\"-1\" aria-checked=\"false\" href=\"#\" rel=\"async-post\" ajaxify=\"\/ajax\/privacy\/simple_save.php?id=8787330733&amp;audience_json=\u00257B\u0025228787330733\u002522\u00253A\u00257B\u002522value\u002522\u00253A\u00252240\u002522\u00257D\u00257D\">\u003ci class=\"mrs itemIcon img sp_7kwant sx_deb81f\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"itemLabel fsm\">Friends\u003cspan class=\"plusLabel hidden_elem fcg\"> (+)\u003c\/span>\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003c\/li>\u003c\/ul>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/div>\u003cselect name=\"audience[8787330733][value]\">\u003coption value=\"\">\u003c\/option>\u003coption value=\"80\" selected=\"1\">Everyone\u003c\/option>\u003coption value=\"50\">Friends of Friends\u003c\/option>\u003coption value=\"40\">Friends\u003c\/option>\u003c\/select>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/li>\u003cli class=\"pvm uiListItem uiListLight uiListVerticalItemBorder\">\u003cdiv class=\"clearfix fbPrivacyConnectItem\">\u003cdiv class=\"privacyLabel lfloat\">Who can send you friend requests?\u003c\/div>\u003cdiv class=\"itemControl rfloat\">\u003cdiv class=\"uiSelector inlineBlock audienceSelector dynamicIconSelector uiSelectorRight uiSelectorNormal uiSelectorDynamicLabel uiSelectorDynamicTooltip\" data-name=\"audience[8787540733][value]\">\u003cdiv class=\"wrap\">\u003ca class=\"uiTooltip uiSelectorButton uiButton\" onmouseout=\"this.blur();\" role=\"button\" href=\"#\" aria-haspopup=\"1\" data-length=\"30\" rel=\"toggle\">\u003ci class=\"mrs defaultIcon customimg img sp_7kwant sx_b2461a\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"uiButtonText\">Everyone\u003c\/span>\u003cspan class=\"uiTooltipWrap top right righttop\">\u003cspan class=\"uiTooltipText uiTooltipNoWrap\">Everyone\u003c\/span>\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003cdiv class=\"uiSelectorMenuWrapper uiToggleFlyout\">\u003cdiv role=\"menu\" class=\"uiMenu uiSelectorMenu\">\u003cul class=\"uiMenuInner\">\u003cli class=\"uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption fbPrivacyAudienceSelectorOption checked\" data-label=\"Everyone\">\u003ca class=\"itemAnchor itemWithIcon\" role=\"menuitemradio\" tabindex=\"0\" aria-checked=\"true\" href=\"#\" rel=\"async-post\" ajaxify=\"\/ajax\/privacy\/simple_save.php?id=8787540733&amp;audience_json=\u00257B\u0025228787540733\u002522\u00253A\u00257B\u002522value\u002522\u00253A\u00252280\u002522\u00257D\u00257D\">\u003ci class=\"mrs itemIcon img sp_7kwant sx_b2461a\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"itemLabel fsm\">Everyone\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003c\/li>\u003cli class=\"uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption fbPrivacyAudienceSelectorOption\" data-label=\"Friends of Friends\">\u003ca class=\"itemAnchor itemWithIcon\" role=\"menuitemradio\" tabindex=\"-1\" aria-checked=\"false\" href=\"#\" rel=\"async-post\" ajaxify=\"\/ajax\/privacy\/simple_save.php?id=8787540733&amp;audience_json=\u00257B\u0025228787540733\u002522\u00253A\u00257B\u002522value\u002522\u00253A\u00252250\u002522\u00257D\u00257D\">\u003ci class=\"mrs itemIcon img sp_8n1pd0 sx_20b2e8\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"itemLabel fsm\">Friends of Friends\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003c\/li>\u003c\/ul>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/div>\u003cselect name=\"audience[8787540733][value]\">\u003coption value=\"\">\u003c\/option>\u003coption value=\"80\" selected=\"1\">Everyone\u003c\/option>\u003coption value=\"50\">Friends of Friends\u003c\/option>\u003c\/select>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/li>\u003cli class=\"pvm uiListItem uiListLight uiListVerticalItemBorder\">\u003cdiv class=\"clearfix fbPrivacyConnectItem\">\u003cdiv class=\"privacyLabel lfloat\">Who can send you Facebook messages?\u003c\/div>\u003cdiv class=\"itemControl rfloat\">\u003cdiv class=\"uiSelector inlineBlock audienceSelector dynamicIconSelector uiSelectorRight uiSelectorNormal uiSelectorDynamicLabel uiSelectorDynamicTooltip\" data-name=\"audience[8787545733][value]\">\u003cdiv class=\"wrap\">\u003ca class=\"uiTooltip uiSelectorButton uiButton\" onmouseout=\"this.blur();\" role=\"button\" href=\"#\" aria-haspopup=\"1\" data-length=\"30\" rel=\"toggle\">\u003ci class=\"mrs defaultIcon customimg img sp_7kwant sx_b2461a\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"uiButtonText\">Everyone\u003c\/span>\u003cspan class=\"uiTooltipWrap top right righttop\">\u003cspan class=\"uiTooltipText uiTooltipNoWrap\">Everyone\u003c\/span>\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003cdiv class=\"uiSelectorMenuWrapper uiToggleFlyout\">\u003cdiv role=\"menu\" class=\"uiMenu uiSelectorMenu\">\u003cul class=\"uiMenuInner\">\u003cli class=\"uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption fbPrivacyAudienceSelectorOption checked\" data-label=\"Everyone\">\u003ca class=\"itemAnchor itemWithIcon\" role=\"menuitemradio\" tabindex=\"0\" aria-checked=\"true\" href=\"#\" rel=\"async-post\" ajaxify=\"\/ajax\/privacy\/simple_save.php?id=8787545733&amp;audience_json=\u00257B\u0025228787545733\u002522\u00253A\u00257B\u002522value\u002522\u00253A\u00252280\u002522\u00257D\u00257D\">\u003ci class=\"mrs itemIcon img sp_7kwant sx_b2461a\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"itemLabel fsm\">Everyone\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003c\/li>\u003cli class=\"uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption fbPrivacyAudienceSelectorOption\" data-label=\"Friends of Friends\">\u003ca class=\"itemAnchor itemWithIcon\" role=\"menuitemradio\" tabindex=\"-1\" aria-checked=\"false\" href=\"#\" rel=\"async-post\" ajaxify=\"\/ajax\/privacy\/simple_save.php?id=8787545733&amp;audience_json=\u00257B\u0025228787545733\u002522\u00253A\u00257B\u002522value\u002522\u00253A\u00252250\u002522\u00257D\u00257D\">\u003ci class=\"mrs itemIcon img sp_8n1pd0 sx_20b2e8\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"itemLabel fsm\">Friends of Friends\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003c\/li>\u003cli class=\"uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption fbPrivacyAudienceSelectorOption\" data-label=\"Friends\">\u003ca class=\"itemAnchor itemWithIcon\" role=\"menuitemradio\" tabindex=\"-1\" aria-checked=\"false\" href=\"#\" rel=\"async-post\" ajaxify=\"\/ajax\/privacy\/simple_save.php?id=8787545733&amp;audience_json=\u00257B\u0025228787545733\u002522\u00253A\u00257B\u002522value\u002522\u00253A\u00252240\u002522\u00257D\u00257D\">\u003ci class=\"mrs itemIcon img sp_7kwant sx_deb81f\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"itemLabel fsm\">Friends\u003cspan class=\"plusLabel hidden_elem fcg\"> (+)\u003c\/span>\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003c\/li>\u003c\/ul>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/div>\u003cselect name=\"audience[8787545733][value]\">\u003coption value=\"\">\u003c\/option>\u003coption value=\"80\" selected=\"1\">Everyone\u003c\/option>\u003coption value=\"50\">Friends of Friends\u003c\/option>\u003coption value=\"40\">Friends\u003c\/option>\u003c\/select>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/li>\u003cli class=\"pvm uiListItem uiListLight uiListVerticalItemBorder\">\u003cdiv class=\"clearfix fbPrivacyConnectItem\">\u003cdiv class=\"privacyLabel lfloat\">Who can post on your Wall?\u003c\/div>\u003cdiv class=\"itemControl rfloat\">\u003cdiv class=\"uiSelector inlineBlock audienceSelector dynamicIconSelector uiSelectorRight uiSelectorNormal uiSelectorDynamicLabel uiSelectorDynamicTooltip\" data-name=\"audience[0][value]\">\u003cdiv class=\"wrap\">\u003ca class=\"uiTooltip uiSelectorButton uiButton\" onmouseout=\"this.blur();\" role=\"button\" href=\"#\" aria-haspopup=\"1\" data-length=\"30\" rel=\"toggle\">\u003ci class=\"mrs defaultIcon customimg img sp_7kwant sx_deb81f\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"uiButtonText\">Friends\u003c\/span>\u003cspan class=\"uiTooltipWrap top right righttop\">\u003cspan class=\"uiTooltipText uiTooltipNoWrap\">Friends\u003c\/span>\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003cdiv class=\"uiSelectorMenuWrapper uiToggleFlyout\">\u003cdiv role=\"menu\" class=\"uiMenu uiSelectorMenu\">\u003cul class=\"uiMenuInner\">\u003cli class=\"uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption fbPrivacyAudienceSelectorOption checked\" data-label=\"Friends\">\u003ca class=\"itemAnchor itemWithIcon\" role=\"menuitemradio\" tabindex=\"0\" aria-checked=\"true\" href=\"#\" rel=\"ignore\">\u003ci class=\"mrs itemIcon img sp_7kwant sx_deb81f\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"itemLabel fsm\">Friends\u003cspan class=\"plusLabel hidden_elem fcg\"> (+)\u003c\/span>\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003c\/li>\u003cli class=\"uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption fbPrivacyAudienceSelectorOption\" data-label=\"Only Me\">\u003ca class=\"itemAnchor itemWithIcon\" role=\"menuitemradio\" tabindex=\"-1\" aria-checked=\"false\" href=\"#\" rel=\"ignore\">\u003ci class=\"mrs itemIcon img sp_dvtjtj sx_e7fbcd\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"itemLabel fsm\">Only Me\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003c\/li>\u003c\/ul>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/div>\u003cselect name=\"audience[0][value]\">\u003coption value=\"\">\u003c\/option>\u003coption value=\"40\" selected=\"1\">Friends\u003c\/option>\u003coption value=\"10\">Only Me\u003c\/option>\u003c\/select>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/li>\u003cli class=\"ptm uiListItem uiListLight uiListVerticalItemBorder\">\u003cdiv class=\"clearfix fbPrivacyConnectItem\">\u003cdiv class=\"privacyLabel lfloat\">Who can see Wall posts by others on your profile?\u003c\/div>\u003cdiv class=\"itemControl rfloat\">\u003cdiv class=\"uiSelector inlineBlock audienceSelector dynamicIconSelector uiSelectorRight uiSelectorNormal uiSelectorDynamicLabel uiSelectorDynamicTooltip\" data-name=\"audience[8787370733][value]\">\u003cdiv class=\"wrap\">\u003ca class=\"uiTooltip uiSelectorButton uiButton\" onmouseout=\"this.blur();\" role=\"button\" href=\"#\" aria-haspopup=\"1\" data-length=\"30\" rel=\"toggle\">\u003ci class=\"mrs defaultIcon customimg img sp_8n1pd0 sx_20b2e8\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"uiButtonText\">Friends of Friends\u003c\/span>\u003cspan class=\"uiTooltipWrap top right righttop\">\u003cspan class=\"uiTooltipText uiTooltipNoWrap\">Friends of Friends\u003c\/span>\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003cdiv class=\"uiSelectorMenuWrapper uiToggleFlyout\">\u003cdiv role=\"menu\" class=\"uiMenu uiSelectorMenu\">\u003cul class=\"uiMenuInner\">\u003cli class=\"uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption fbPrivacyAudienceSelectorOption\" data-label=\"Public\">\u003ca class=\"itemAnchor itemWithIcon\" role=\"menuitemradio\" tabindex=\"0\" aria-checked=\"false\" href=\"#\" rel=\"async-post\" ajaxify=\"\/ajax\/privacy\/simple_save.php?id=8787370733&amp;audience_json=\u00257B\u0025228787370733\u002522\u00253A\u00257B\u002522value\u002522\u00253A\u00252280\u002522\u00257D\u00257D\">\u003ci class=\"mrs itemIcon img sp_7kwant sx_b2461a\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"itemLabel fsm\">Public\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003c\/li>\u003cli class=\"uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption fbPrivacyAudienceSelectorOption checked\" data-label=\"Friends of Friends\">\u003ca class=\"itemAnchor itemWithIcon\" role=\"menuitemradio\" tabindex=\"-1\" aria-checked=\"true\" href=\"#\" rel=\"async-post\" ajaxify=\"\/ajax\/privacy\/simple_save.php?id=8787370733&amp;audience_json=\u00257B\u0025228787370733\u002522\u00253A\u00257B\u002522value\u002522\u00253A\u00252250\u002522\u00257D\u00257D\">\u003ci class=\"mrs itemIcon img sp_8n1pd0 sx_20b2e8\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"itemLabel fsm\">Friends of Friends\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003c\/li>\u003cli class=\"uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption fbPrivacyAudienceSelectorOption\" data-label=\"Friends\">\u003ca class=\"itemAnchor itemWithIcon\" role=\"menuitemradio\" tabindex=\"-1\" aria-checked=\"false\" href=\"#\" rel=\"async-post\" ajaxify=\"\/ajax\/privacy\/simple_save.php?id=8787370733&amp;audience_json=\u00257B\u0025228787370733\u002522\u00253A\u00257B\u002522value\u002522\u00253A\u00252240\u002522\u00257D\u00257D\">\u003ci class=\"mrs itemIcon img sp_7kwant sx_deb81f\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"itemLabel fsm\">Friends\u003cspan class=\"plusLabel hidden_elem fcg\"> (+)\u003c\/span>\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003c\/li>\u003cli class=\"uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption fbPrivacyAudienceSelectorOption\" data-label=\"Only Me\">\u003ca class=\"itemAnchor itemWithIcon\" role=\"menuitemradio\" tabindex=\"-1\" aria-checked=\"false\" href=\"#\" rel=\"async-post\" ajaxify=\"\/ajax\/privacy\/simple_save.php?id=8787370733&amp;audience_json=\u00257B\u0025228787370733\u002522\u00253A\u00257B\u002522value\u002522\u00253A\u00252210\u002522\u00257D\u00257D\">\u003ci class=\"mrs itemIcon img sp_dvtjtj sx_e7fbcd\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"itemLabel fsm\">Only Me\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003c\/li>\u003cli class=\"uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption fbPrivacyAudienceSelectorOption\" data-label=\"Custom\" id=\"uo28p0_1\">\u003ca class=\"itemAnchor itemWithIcon\" role=\"menuitemradio\" tabindex=\"-1\" aria-checked=\"false\" href=\"#\" rel=\"ignore\">\u003ci class=\"mrs itemIcon img sp_7kwant sx_bd80ab\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"itemLabel fsm\">Custom\u003cspan class=\"customPrivacyInputs\">\u003c\/span>\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003c\/li>\u003cli class=\"uiMenuSeparator\">\u003c\/li>\u003cli class=\"uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption fbPrivacyAudienceSelectorOption friendListOption specialOption primaryOption\" data-label=\"Close Friends\">\u003ca class=\"itemAnchor itemWithIcon\" role=\"menuitemradio\" tabindex=\"-1\" aria-checked=\"false\" href=\"#\" rel=\"async-post\" ajaxify=\"\/ajax\/privacy\/simple_save.php?id=8787370733&amp;audience_json=\u00257B\u0025228787370733\u002522\u00253A\u00257B\u002522value\u002522\u00253A\u002522119853121454552\u002522\u00257D\u00257D\">\u003ci class=\"mrs itemIcon img sp_7kwant sx_dfa161\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"itemLabel fsm\">Close Friends\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003c\/li>\u003cli class=\"uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption fbPrivacyAudienceSelectorOption friendListOption specialOption primaryOption\" data-label=\"Family\">\u003ca class=\"itemAnchor itemWithIcon\" role=\"menuitemradio\" tabindex=\"-1\" aria-checked=\"false\" href=\"#\" rel=\"async-post\" ajaxify=\"\/ajax\/privacy\/simple_save.php?id=8787370733&amp;audience_json=\u00257B\u0025228787370733\u002522\u00253A\u00257B\u002522value\u002522\u00253A\u002522119853124787885\u002522\u00257D\u00257D\">\u003ci class=\"mrs itemIcon img sp_7kwant sx_227950\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"itemLabel fsm\">Family\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003c\/li>\u003cli class=\"uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption fbPrivacyAudienceSelectorOption friendListOption specialOption primaryOption\" data-label=\"Acquaintances\">\u003ca class=\"itemAnchor itemWithIcon\" role=\"menuitemradio\" tabindex=\"-1\" aria-checked=\"false\" href=\"#\" rel=\"async-post\" ajaxify=\"\/ajax\/privacy\/simple_save.php?id=8787370733&amp;audience_json=\u00257B\u0025228787370733\u002522\u00253A\u00257B\u002522value\u002522\u00253A\u002522100002895945078_124542800973931\u002522\u00257D\u00257D\">\u003ci class=\"mrs itemIcon img sp_7kwant sx_59bac9\">\u003c\/i>\u003cspan class=\"itemLabel fsm\">Acquaintances\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003c\/li>\u003cli class=\"uiMenuSeparator secondaryOption\">\u003c\/li>\u003cli class=\"uiMenuItem uiMenuItemRadio uiSelectorOption returnOption secondaryOption specialOption\" data-label=\"Return\">\u003ca class=\"itemAnchor\" role=\"menuitemradio\" tabindex=\"-1\" aria-checked=\"false\" href=\"#\" rel=\"ignore\">\u003cspan class=\"itemLabel fsm\">Return\u003c\/span>\u003c\/a>\u003c\/li>\u003c\/ul>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/div>\u003cselect name=\"audience[8787370733][value]\">\u003coption value=\"\">\u003c\/option>\u003coption value=\"80\">Public\u003c\/option>\u003coption value=\"50\" selected=\"1\">Friends of Friends\u003c\/option>\u003coption value=\"40\">Friends\u003c\/option>\u003coption value=\"10\">Only Me\u003c\/option>\u003coption value=\"111\">Custom\u003c\/option>\u003coption value=\"119853121454552\">Close Friends\u003c\/option>\u003coption value=\"119853124787885\">Family\u003c\/option>\u003coption value=\"100002895945078_124542800973931\">Acquaintances\u003c\/option>\u003coption value=\"Return\">Return\u003c\/option>\u003c\/select>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/div>\u003c\/li>\u003c\/ul>\u003c\/div>"},"contentWidth":540,"fullBleed":false,"buttons":[{"name":"done","label":"Done","handler":"Dialog.getCurrent().hide()"}],"buttonsMessage":"\u003ca href=\"\/help\/privacy\">Learn more\u003c\/a>","postURI":["\/ajax\/settings\/privacy\/connections_can_post_save.php",true],"secure":false},"css":["Fe9Fn","6x0ig","tWyR7"],"js":["poN6f","VVPTI"],"onload":["JSCC.get('j4e8ca57f0a8f045518753661').init(\"uo28p0_1\", \"8787370733\", true, \"\", true);"],"bootloadable":{"async":["LayX0","Vroh4","6liCk"],"iframe-shim":["LayX0","Vroh4","YxBS7"],"maxlength-form-listener":["LayX0","Vroh4","poN6f"],"dom-scroll":["LayX0","Vroh4","poN6f"],"animation":["LayX0","Vroh4"]},"resource_map":{"Fe9Fn":{"type":"css","src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/y9\/r\/gpPkWs8bLEo.css"},"6x0ig":{"type":"css","permanent":1,"nonblocking":1,"src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yR\/r\/ITJh_KJve0v.css"},"tWyR7":{"type":"css","nonblocking":1,"src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yn\/r\/U1Xcl_cw8Or.css"},"poN6f":{"type":"js","src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/y-\/r\/AkEj5nFsB5x.js"},"VVPTI":{"type":"js","src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yC\/r\/K1e4uscht3y.js"},"LayX0":{"type":"js","src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yj\/r\/-eXzfKGl5Cz.js"},"Vroh4":{"type":"js","src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/y8\/r\/7Htnnss1mJY.js"},"6liCk":{"type":"css","permanent":1,"src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/y_\/r\/WsQZCwjJUxu.css"},"YxBS7":{"type":"js","src":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yc\/r\/DzkM-7DYccQ.js"}},"jscc":"JSCC.init({\"j4e8ca57f0a8f045518753661\":function(){return new CustomPrivacyOption();}});"}
```

now i want to examine the settings (It's a dialog-box). I want to put it into the DOM and extracting the information using jquery.

Comment: You may want to consider simplifying and formatting your example code.

Comment: Sorry, i think it's better here: http://pastie.org/private/gk7fnfkretolkqd8xlmqhw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks you Wladimir Palant and Xeon06.

I found the right way with your help ;)
here the full code for everyone who got the same problem

```
response = response.replace(/.*?;{/, "{");                        
jsonFile = JSON.parse(response);
$('#globalContainer').append(jsonFile.payload.body.__html)
```

Comment: You should mark this as the answer to your question by clicking the green checkmark next to it. You can also thank people who helped you by clicking the up arrow next to their answers.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've removed the `for` at the beggining and parsed it, you could do something like this to put it in a `div`:

```
$('#yourdiv').html(yourJSONObject.body.__html);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse that file, don't forget to remove `for (;;);` at the beginning of it. Something like:

```
var fileData = ...;
var json = JSON.parse(fileData.replace(/.*?;{/, "{"));
div.innerHTML = json.payload.body.html;
```

Comment: I tried this:   
  
`response = response.replace(/.*?;{/, "{"); 
jsonFile = JSON.parse(response); 
$('#globalContainer').append(jsonFile.payload.body.html);` 
  
but nothing happend... i tried this as a test which worked without any problems: `$('#globalContainer').append('<h2> Power of selectors </h2>');`